# Interprocess communication between MFC and WPF

Tags: c++, wpf, mfc, ipc, interprocess

I'm trying to establish a two way communication between a mfc application and a wpf application. I'm taking help from these two articles: 
[Interprocess Communication Between .NET and MFC Using WM_COPYDATA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22402/Interprocess-Communication-Between-NET-and-MFC-Usi) and [Interprocess Communication Between .NET and MFC Using C# and COPYDATA](http://davidjwalling.com/pro_cs_20100825_001.html)

So far i have managed to send message from wpf to mfc. But now i want mfc application to send the message to wpf application. What do i need to do it to achieve this?

On mfc side, I'm storing the handle as

`storedHandle = (HWND)intPtr;`

and later using this handle to send message with the following line:

`::SendMessage(pFrame->storedHandle, WM_COPYDATA, 0, 0);`

But wpf is not receiving is message.

Comment: Show the actual code which you are using. Don't just put link. One problem might be that you are sending data from 32bit program to 64bit program

Comment: There are a number of ways to implement [interprocess communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx). Using pipes is potentially more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using legacy window-based communication you should consider a more contemporary mechanism like Windows Mailslots:

For C# there is a wrapper here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623268/Csharp-wrapper-for-Mailslots

Messages can also be accessed via filesystem using `\\.\mailslot`:

https://blog.didierstevens.com/2006/07/13/do-you-have-mailslots-on-your-windows-pc/